# Include target variable for multivariate outlier detection?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, outliers, anomaly-detection, dbscan

Suppose you have data containing a set of features and a target variable you wish to model. You obviously want to remove any outliers from your data.  Univariate approaches may not be sufficient as some seemingly abnormal values of a single feature may not be so abnormal when considering the values of other features altogether.

When using a multivariate outlier detection technique (mahanalobis distance, DBSCAN noise, OPTICS noise, Local Outlier Factor, etc...), should one include the target variable as well as the input variables, or is only including the input variables better practice?  Thanks!